# Software for interactive webcast recording

Tags: windows, video, video-editing, screen-recording, video-conferencing

Can you recommend to me some software for Windows 10 that records audio/video from webcam that can be later uploaded to Youtube?

I saw some broadcasters usinginteractive ones, where they can switch video to images or videos on a click notice while recording, then switch back to the cam. No postproducion, switched on the fly during recording.

Comment: As your question stands, it's a little unclear how it is being asked. Could you provide more information/explanation on what you mean by "interactive ones". Also, would the green background be a small part of the screen while recording, the entire screen, or something to do with the interactive part of the screen recording software?

Comment: I explained, I want to able to switch from cam to images or video clips while recording instead of chopping it during postproduction. (Removed green screen part.)

Comment: ok, so I'm assuming this would be something you'd have ready to go before you start recording?